# cypher query returning counts of nodes in resultset with different property values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph model where there are `post` nodes representing posts and  `comment` nodes representing comments on posts:

```
    (p:post)<-[:ON]-(c:comment{role:'question'}) 
    (p:post)<-[:ON]-(c:comment{role:'criticism'})
```

Each comment has a `role` property that is one of five possible values. I want to write a query that returns the total number of comments of each role on a given initiative.

This:

```
MATCH (:item:initiative{urlCode:'AAECyS'})<-[:TO]-(c:comment) WITH     
COLLECT(c) AS comments
RETURN {
    question:length(filter(x IN comments WHERE x.role = 'question')),
    criticism:length(filter(x IN comments WHERE x.role = 'criticism'))
    //etc. for other three types
}
```

gives me what I want - but it feels awfully ugly to me.

Is there a cleaner/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest query (you'd get a row per role):

```
MATCH (:item:initiative{urlCode:'AAECyS'})<-[:TO]-(c:comment) 
RETURN c.role, count(*);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a collection and return a collection of instead and that would be neater.

```
MATCH (:item:initiative{urlCode:'AAECyS'})<-[:TO]-(c:comment) 
WITH [c.role, count(*)] as role_count
RETURN collect(role_count) as role_counts
```